# How to interpret coefficients returned from `LinearRegression().coef_` when using polynomial regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, non-linear-regression, quadratic

I have a training set of data `x_train` with 6 features/variables and with target `y_train`. These are stored in `pandas` dataframes.

I have done Linear Regression on this to get a model of the form `y = b + m_1*x_1 + m_2*x_2 + ... + m_6*x_6`. When I print `LinearRegression().coef_`, I get a numpy array that looks like this: `[[m_1, m_2, m_3, m_4, m_5, m_6]]`. From this, I am able to extract the coefficients `mi` just fine.

Now I am trying to do Quadratic Regression on this data instead. I expect this to give me a model of the form `y = b + m_{11}*x_1 + m_{12}*x_1^2 + m_{21}*x_2 + m_{22}*x_2^2 + ... + m_{62}*x_6^2`. So I expect that I should get 12 coefficients, `m_11, m_12, m_21, m_22, m_31, m_32, m_41, m_42, m_51, m_52, m_61, m_62`. Instead, when I print `qm.coef_` as shown in the code below, I get a numpy array of length 28:

```py
>>> print(qm.coef_)
[ 5.23243620e-08 -4.52818442e+01 -1.69803868e-02  1.23876223e+00
 -1.31251424e+01  6.34950041e+01 -5.65064601e-02 -3.04164916e+00
  1.22800976e-03 -1.81908736e-02 -1.38319879e+00 -1.88468027e+00
  8.98960781e-03 -5.10163574e-07  5.60756672e-04 -8.52068126e-04
 -5.09033748e-03  2.67482109e-06  1.10815787e-01 -7.45059709e-01
 -1.05108447e+00  6.37628573e-05 -9.12589844e-01 -1.22173903e+00
 -5.47228030e-04  6.34950042e+01 -5.39225901e-03  2.21487661e-06]
```

My question is, why do I get 28? Where are the 12 that I am looking for, and what are the other 16 coefficients?

---

Here is my code:

```py
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_poly = poly.fit_transform(x_train)
poly.fit(X_poly, y_train)
qm = LinearRegression()
qm.fit(X_poly, y_train)
print(qm.coef_)
```

---

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813488/how-to-interpret-multivariate-polynomial-coefficients-in-pythons-scikitlearn-pa) which was unanswered. [Another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54253388/coefficients-of-polynomial-in-polynomial-regression) which wasn't answered correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not programming question, but here's explanation:

There are 6 features, so a1*x1 + a2*x2 .. +  a6*x6  will make 6 thetas.
Now their squared as features, so a7*x1^2 + a8*x2^2 + .. + a12*x6^2 will make another 6 thetas.
Now combinations like x1*x2 and so on will make 6C2 thetas ie 15.
Also, at last, the origin shifting theta a0,
Thus total: 1 + 12 + 15 = 28 thetas

Comment: Ahh yes I forgot about those. Ok so which is which in the array? How are they ordered? eg if the model is `y = a0 + a1 x1 + a2 x2 + a11 x1^2 + a22 x2^2 + a12 x1 x2`, then in what order are the `a0, a1, a2, a11, a22, a12` displayed?

Comment: @JohnDoe Idk, but why does the order matter?  You'll always need all those thetas together.

Comment: Because I wanted to write the function out, with the actual values of the coefficients, so that I can plot some graphs. However, I am now thinking it can probably be done without knowing the values of the coefficients - by using the `.predict()` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting that `Polynomial regression` uses cross products between the variables aswell, not just the variables squared. When you are using the `fit` for the polynomial, you are not working only with the `grade 1` and `grade 2` variables, but with the cross products too:

In the case a two variable regression `(X1, X2)`, you will expect to have 5 coeficients:

```
Y = m1 * x1 + m2 * x2 + m3 * x1 ** 2 + m4 * x2 ** x2 + m5 * x1 * x2
```

Furthermore, in your case of 6 variables there are 16 possible combinations between the variables. Taking into account you have `6` grade 1 variables, `6` grade 2 variables and `15` combination between them, plus the base parameter: `6 + 6 + 15 + 1 = 28`.

Comment: Ahh yes I forgot about those. Ok so which is which in the array? How are they ordered? eg if the model is `y = a0 + a1 x1 + a2 x2 + a11 x1^2 + a22 x2^2 + a12 x1 x2`, then in what order are the `a0, a1, a2, a11, a22, a12` displayed?